# docbook maxwidth on images? (xml:fo)

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, docbook

is there a way to specify the maximum width of images in a docbook xsl-transform?

we have a problem with screen shots being to big to fit on a page, and thus would like to set a max width on images in the output.

specifying the width of the image in the Docbook XML files seems bad form (the Docbook file should be about content not presentation), a lot of manual work, and likely inconsistent sizes

so is there a handy way to do this?

image.default.width is not usefull because that alters images smaller then the 'page' width as well.

Comment: I believe David answered your question. You should mark it as such so folks like me immediately know what to copy/paste ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846703/docbook-maxwidth-on-images-xmlfo/1848095#1848095) got very close with the [correct link](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/ImageSizing.html) but missed the critical phrase on that page:

> To keep a graphic for printed output at its natural size unless it is too large to fit the available width, in which case shrink it to fit, use `scalefit="1"`, `width="100%"`, and `contentdepth="100%"` attributes.

That suggestion works well for a PDF generated by `fop`. If you're also generating HTML documentation, you'll have to add the following CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

You can include CSS via:

```
$ xsltproc --stringparam html.stylesheet doc.css ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `<imagedata width="100%" scalefit="1">`. It's on each image in the source XML I know, but it will scale with various output media sizes.

Check out [this page on image sizing](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/ImageSizing.html)

Comment: +1 for mentioning Bob Stayton's book. Images usually (ok, bitmap images) tend to have a fixed size so referring to it doesn't seem to be a bad thing.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but this scales all images to the specified width.
but i was looking to only scale images which dont fit.
+1 for the book link tho